# Timedelta to "%H:%M" format

Tags: pandas, timedelta

Is there a way to convert `timedelta` columns to strings in the "%H:%M" format? I need this even for `timedelta`s with more than 24 hours

I want to do this to make a .csv file that can be used in spreadsheets-like softwares (excel, google sheets...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's nothing built-in. You have to roll your own:

```
s = pd.to_timedelta(['0:10:00', '12:34:56', '25:12:34']).to_series()
s.dt.total_seconds().apply(lambda s: f'{s // 3600:02.0f}:{(s % 3600) // 60:02.0f}')
```

Result:

```
0 days 00:10:00    00:10
0 days 12:34:56    12:34
1 days 01:12:34    25:12
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping for a built-in, but you were very kind for doing this one-liner!
What does `':02.0f'` means?

Comment: That's the format string. It tells Python to 0-pad the string to length 2, and use no decimal point

Answer (score 1):

With some integer and remainder division you can use the `total_seconds` to figure out how to format your string. This method currently ignores milliseconds.

```
def format_timedelta(s):
    s = s.dt.total_seconds()

    seconds = (s%60).astype(int).astype(str).str.zfill(2)
    minutes = (s//60%60).astype(int).astype(str).str.zfill(2)
    hours = (s//3600).astype(int).astype(str)

    return hours+':'+minutes+':'+seconds


s = pd.Series(pd.to_timedelta(['24:20:00', '00:15:00', '123:12:12', 
                               '123:02:12', '4:20:00.1123']))

format_timedelta(s)
0     24:20:00
1      0:15:00
2    123:12:12
3    123:02:12
dtype: object
```