# Read time with 'hh:mm:ss' format in sas7bdat to pandas

Tags: pandas, sas

I use command `pd.read_sas('E:\file.sas7bdat',encoding = 'latin1')` to read SAS data into df and the time column turns into number as below:

original in SAS:7:50:00

appear in df: 28200.0

Can you please help to turn it to time?

Answer (score 1):

7:50:00 is 28200 seconds.

It looks like, although displaying `7:50`, SAS is actually storing the data as seconds.

Convert using [`pandas.to_timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html):

```
df['time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['time'], unit='s')
```

If you further want to convert to a string with the `%H:%M:%S` format, refer to [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61642963/16343464).

Comment: SAS stores datetimes as seconds in  a double. Epoch date is Jan 1, 1960. If the library is reading the value, that is what is being read. SAS has no date or datetime data type. Only strings or doubles. HTH.

Comment: @AlanC thanks for the info. If OP wants a date relative to this epoch, then `df['time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['time'], unit='s').add(pd.Timestamp('1960-01-01'))` should be used.

Comment: This is a SAS time (number of seconds since midnight) rather than a SAS datetime (number of seconds since Jan 1, 1960).  So answer looks correct to me.